# How can I return the average customer balance with the dollar sign removed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsefloat

I'm trying to utilize this code to return the average customer balance without the dollar sign or comma. I'm using .reduce because I feel like that's the best option here. Additionally, I'm trying out parseFloat for the first time so I'm just not sure I'm using it correctly. The objective here is

1. convert string to number and replace dollar sign and comma with nothing
2. sum all the balances
3. return the average balance
4. use .reduce

```
var people = [
  {
    name: "Courtney",
    age: 43, 
    balance: "$3,400"
  },
  {
    name: "Regina",
    age: 53,
    balance: "$4,000"
  },
  {
    name: "Jay",
    age: 28,
    balance: "$3,000"
  },
]

var averageBalance = function(array){
   var average = people.reduce(function(acc, current, index, array){
     if(index === array.length - 1){
       return acc / array.length; 
     }
     return acc += parseFloat(current.balance.replace(/\$|,/g, ""));
   }, 0); 
 return average;
}
```

Comment: When the `index === array.length - 1` triggers, the last number is not added... You just do the division. That is why your result is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do too much inside your `.reduce` body. `.reduce` lets you do something *to every element* of an array - such as add them all up. If you want to do *one thing* separately (like divide by the length of the array to get the average), that should be put outside the `.reduce` callback.

```js
var people = [{
    name: "Courtney",
    age: 43,
    balance: "$3,400"
  },
  {
    name: "Regina",
    age: 53,
    balance: "$4,000"
  },
  {
    name: "Jay",
    age: 28,
    balance: "$3,000"
  },
]

var averageBalance = function(array) {
  const sum = people.reduce(function(acc, current) {
    return acc + Number(current.balance.replace(/\$|,/g, ""));
  }, 0);
  return sum / people.length;
}
console.log(averageBalance(people));
```